# When mapping a keyboard... What are "dead keys", "terminators", and "states"?

Tags: custom-keyboard, dead-key

After reading the Ukelele keyboard manual (http://iran.clubmgenretraites.paris/Logiciels/Emul/8-16Bits/ZX&Cie/Mac/Spectrum&Cie/Ukulele/Ukelele%20Manual%202.2.pdf) & reading through many Github & StackOverflow posts on the topic, I still don't understand what these are. Almost no videos come up on YouTube. Can someone demonstrate what these do?

Answer (score 2):

Dead keys can add accents on the top of the letters. For example you can also find it on the default spanish keyboard (Spanish - ISO). If you press key "´" (on the right next to the "ñ") and a key "a" after that, the result will be á. So in this case the key "´" is the terminator key. Dead key state is the setup of accents which is entered by its terminator key. In Ukulele you can create different dead key states (1,2,3,4,5) and assign a particular terminator key to enter them. This is very useful for multilanguage people who can set up dead key states for different languages and don't need to switch keyboards every time they need to add the accents.

Comment: Could someone give an example like with the à for a dead key state and a terminator?